# Allowing Use of Form Controls in Excel using Android Tablet

Tags: excel, forms, controls, activex

Can anyone help me in allowing use of form controls using excel in my android tablet? and how can i change protection in the excel in tablet? i cannot open review tab in the tablet. Thanks.

Comment: Does "tell me" (light bulb) feature provide any assistance? <Looks doubtful> And do you know if the file is protected?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the short answer to both your questions is send it to a 
computer. On a computer remove protection and make any changes with form controls required and then resend to your tablet.

You will need Office 365 on your tablet to get the maximum use of features though these additional features seems to be limited, for Excel, to [SmartArt](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/when-do-i-need-an-office-365-subscription-b6518311-893a-4a89-bfcd-bdc56bf52085).

Without 365, and with protection removed (via computer), you should be able to access the review tab on your tablet and add, for example, worksheet protection. The latter bit is according to Microsoft Support (case reference 1419182369). I haven't been able to test as I don't have a tablet.

As far as I could find out, the workbooks with form controls are now "enabled" - basically, these files will open but there will be placeholders where these controls are; as opposed to functional objects.

See here for information:  https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304939-excel-for-android/suggestions/15075030-support-form-controls

Further help information around Android Tablet Excel features:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-for-android-tablets-help-5f089a58-dfa5-4cdb-b93b-55deb638a469

The current ideas proposed for Android Excel in relation to Macros and Add-Ins:

https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304939-excel-for-android?category_id=143592

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you so much for this. But I still cant use my form controls in my tablet (check box type of form control).

Comment: What i think I meant above is that at present you can't use them on Tablet. If you want to make changes using the controls send it to a desktop/laptop and make required changes with controls there. At present, on tablet, I believe the controls are just placeholders and not active content.